# triggering email from custom module

Tags: 6, hooks, emails

I have a module that uses hook_menu to create several pages that are populated with SQL query results.

I have been trying to configure drupal_mail and hook_mail to send these results via mail when the pages are visited, but so far I haven't succeeded.

I used the info I found [here](http://www.cleverlogic.net/tutorials/sending-html-and-plain-text-mail-drupal-6) and indeed, the module works: whenever I run cron the sample mail is sent, but I haven't found the way to customize it in my module so when I load my custom pages the results are sent via mail.

Also, if my data is the result of:

```
function mystats_all() {

$header = array('Nombre', 'Status', 'Rol 5 = Alumno', 'Email' );

$query = "
SELECT name, status, rid, mail
FROM users
JOIN users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
WHERE mail NOT LIKE '%@example.com' 
AND users_roles.rid =5
AND users.status =1
";

$result = db_query($query, $some_value);
    while ($row = db_fetch_object($result))
    { 
        $rows[] = array(
                    array('data' => $row->name, 'align' =>'left'),
                    array('data' => $row->status, 'align' => 'left'),
                    array('data' => $row->rid, 'align' => 'center'),    
                    array('data' => $row->mail, 'align' => 'left'),    

        );
    }

    $table_attributes = array('id' => 'my_id_for_table', 'align' => 'center');
    $output .= theme('table', $header, $rows, $table_attributes);

    return $output;
```

how can I correctly send my table via mail? I don't know (and I would like to have the drupal_mail function working to make some tests) if I should use $query or $result.

Thanx in advance.

Any ideas or help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [hook_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_mail/6) in your custom module and then call [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/6) in your page callback function to get the result you want. You should save your table html in the `$params` array that gets delivered to `hook_mail()` and then set it as the `$message['body']` value there (with additional html/data if needed). The linked tutorial and API pages should give you enough information and examples to work out the rest of the details.

Comment: This is pretty much how I made it work, Dooshta. My problem now is that I have several queries in this module and I would love to be able to trigger the mails independently when you visit each url generated via hook_menu.

Comment: @MauF If the page callback functions are different for every defined menu item then you can run the necessary queries and send the specific e-mail(s) depending of the page visited (or am I not quite understanding what you want to achieve?).

Comment: Yes, I do have specific callbacks. This means I have to code a specific hook_mail for every callback, right?

Comment: @MauF You can only have one hook_mail() function, but you can define different e-mail implementations within it. drupal_mail() also allows you to deliver data to hook_mail() (via the $params array) so the mail content/title can differ depending of the data sent. You can check the tutorial you linked about how it's done on the code level.

Comment: Will do, Dooshta. Thanx.